# Notification for image load in os x kernel

Tags: c, macos, driver, kernel-extension

is there any way to receive a notification that a new image was loaded into a desired task?
i know that in user mode I can use
`_dyld_register_func_for_add_image`
but is there any way to do that from kernel?

I know that it seems pretty impossible since dyld is responsible for all the loading process and it's all in the user space.

but maybe someone ever done that before?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/monitor-file-system-events-and-dylib-loading-via-macf-on-macos.html) provides an example of how to detect dyld load events; see the "Monitor Dylib Loading Event" section. It does so using a Mandatory Access Control Framework (MACF) kext to inspect `mpo_file_check_mmap` events.

It's not the most friendly or complete tutorial about MACF, so you might want to read [this MACF tutorial](https://www.synack.com/2015/11/17/monitoring-process-creation-via-the-kernel-part-i/) first if you're new to MACF.